# Android: start manually service failed on release version

Tags: android, service, filter

I develop an Android app for my pcDuino board. There is Android 4.2 version on it.

In AndroidManifest.xml, I have my service:

```
    <service
        android:name="com.compagny.myapp.service.HTTPService"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <!-- To allow start the Android service (for debugging session) -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I want to debug it, so I added this filter.

From my laptop, I can deploy in debug and release version my application, but when I want to start my app in release mode, it doesn't work. I can see the service into application manager from my pcDuino board, but nothing happens (even traces in Logcat!).

I start my service from a command line:
am startservice -n com.compagny.myapp/com.compagny.myapp.service.HTTPService

Comment: is it legal to put intent filter main and launcher in service tag

Comment: if I am not wrong android.intent.category.LAUNCHER is valid only for Activity. So, does not look like valid way to start Service

Comment: It works with debug mode. I added this filter according some informations found here.

Comment: I found the problem: in my service I added this line to wait the debugger: android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger(); in the onCreate method.